# Strange issue trying to unlink() my image

Tags: php

Im deleting images that I have in my table "banners", my sql delete is working fine.

But I also want to delete my images from the folder, so Im using unlink() for this purpose.

But its not working, the images are removed from database, but dont remove from the folder.

I really dont understand why this is happening, because directory is correctly!

**Here I have my action link to delete:**

```
 echo ' <td>
         <a href="dashboard.php?exe=banner/banners&delbanner='.$readBannerResult['id'].'&img='.$readBannerResult['img'].'">
            Delete
         </a>
       </td>';
```

**Here I have a link to confirm delete:**

```
echo '<span>You really want to Delete?
<a href="dashboard.php?exe=banner/banners">No</a> 
<a href="dashboard.php?exe=banner/banners&delbannertrue='.$readBannerResult['id'].'">Yes
</a>
</span>';
```

**This is my php:**

```
if(!empty($_GET['delbannertrue']))
    {
        $thumb = $_GET['img'];
        $year   = date('Y');
        $month  = date('m');
        $folder = '../banner-images/';

 if(file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$thumb) && !is_dir($folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$thumb.'/'))
    {
        unlink($folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$thumb);
    }

        $delbannerTrue = $_GET['delbannertrue'];
        $delBanner = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM banners WHERE id =? ");
        $delBanner->bindValue(1,$delbannerTrue);
        $delBanner->execute(); 
        header('Location: dashboard.php?exe=banner/banners');

         }
```

Comment: What is the return value from `unlink()`? Do you have permission to delete this file? Try adding `echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$thumb)), -4);` to your code

Comment: Very strange, now I put the unlink() part, outside my if(!empty($_GET['delbannertrue'])) and it worked...But I just want to remove if "delbannertrue" exists...

Comment: Thanks for your answer squeamish ossifrage but its not that the problem, because of what I said before, if I put this unlink() part, outside my if..it works!

Comment: You might also want to sanitize `$thumb` or your code could be vulnerable to a dot dot slash attack

Comment: `$_GET['img']` – where exactly is that value supposed to come from, if you have only two parameters namend `exe` an `delbannertrue` in your link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is looking for the image name, note:

```
    $thumb = $_GET['img'];

    unlink($folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$thumb);
```

Your "confirm delete" URL however doesn't include the `img` param.
Add this to the URL, as you did with the initial delete link and it should be fine.

Change,

```
<a href="dashboard.php?exe=banner/banners&delbannertrue='.$readBannerResult['id'].'">Yes
```

To,

```
<a href="dashboard.php?exe=banner/banners&delbannertrue='.$readBannerResult['id'].'&img='.$readBannerResult['img'].'">Yes
```

Comment: Sure!! and I was here about one hour looking at the code and not realized it, thank you so much for your help!